# How should I handle a question that has been answered (properly), but gives me a very similar error?

Tags: discussion, edits

So I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320068/why-does-my-activity-get-destroyed-on-adding-a-fragment) question a while back, and I got an answer on it that did indeed fix the issue I was having. This left me with a new error, which I was able to fix myself. Now, though, I've got pretty much the exact same error I had before (which was fixed by the answer), which I *can't* fix using the answer I was given before. Should I edit the question to ask what's causing the issue this time (like I already did), or should I ask a new question?

To recap: Error got fixed by answer, but returned in a slightly different place later, and can't be fixed with the original answer. Edit question to ask what's causing it this time, or ask a new question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the current answer does *not* answer your current question, then it's a different question. Don't change the old question to your new one, however. This would invalidate the current answer (since it would now be incorrect) and is considered bad form.

If you're *absolutely positive* that the old answer does not fix the new issue, then, after you've done a bit more research to make sure you can't find another solution yourself, it *is* allowed to ask another question along the same lines.

Be warned, however, that if you don't make it *very, very clear* that the other answer does not answer your current problem your new question will very likely be downvoted and closed as a duplicate of your old one.

To make this clear, I suggest explaining that you've tried that answer (perhaps even linking to it for more context, but make sure you outline what exactly you tried so other users don't have to visit your original question.) and why/how exactly it didn't work. Be sure to explain the full problem in your new question. You can (and really should) link to the old question for context, but *do not* rely on that to explain the situation. Your new question needs to stand on its own so users don't have to go to any other pages to answer your new question.

Your new question could still be closed as a duplicate after all this. The likely reason for this would be your new code missed something with the answer, and it really came down to a typo/syntax error that you glossed over. (This happens to everyone, it can be hard to see one typo in a wall of code.) If this is the case, it may even be closed for "simple typographical error" instead of duplicate. If you make it extremely clear that you tried the previous answer with the new issue and how it didn't work (including errors!) your new question shouldn't get closed just because it's the same problem, at the very least.

Just to reiterate, as it's extremely important to doing this correctly, *make sure you explain that you tried the previous solution and it did not work for this case, how/why it didn't work, and any errors that it gave you.*